# Is it possible to pass GDAL Config Options to GeoServer on startup

Tags: gdal, geoserver, ecw

GeoServer crushes on request to render big ECW image. [Here](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-4393?focusedCommentId=39580) it was suggested to control the memory that GDAL uses via the GDAL_CACHEMAX env var. Where should I specify this options? Is it
applicable to GeoServer?

Comment: how are you running GeoServer and on what sort of machine?

Comment: JVM on Windows machine. To startup GeoServer I use bat-file with port number, MAX_HEAP_SIZE etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a windows machine I would just add that environment variable to the system in the normal way.